# Why does FastAPI's Depends() work without any parameter passed to it?

Tags: python, dependency-injection, fastapi, depends

I found the following FastAPI code for authenticating a user with their information gotten from a form:

```py
@app.post("/token")

async def login_for_access_token(form_data:OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),
                                 db: Session = Depends(get_db)):

    user = authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password, db)
    if not user:
        raise token_exception()
    
    token_expires = timedelta(minutes=20)
    
    token = create_access_token(user.username,
                                user.id,
                                expires_delta=token_expires)
    return {"token": token}
```

I'm struggling to understand why in `form_data:OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()`, `Depends()` has no parameter passed to it? I thought that the whole point of `Depends()` was to be instantiated with a function that gets called before the endpoint function is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order **to avoid code repetition**, FastAPI allows declaring the dependency as the `type` of the parameter, and using `Depends()` **without** any parameter in it. For instance:

```
form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()
```

Hence, since you have already declared `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm` as the `type` of the `form_data` parameter, there is no need to pass it to the `Depends()` as well.

As per [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#shortcut):

> ### Shortcut
>
> But you see that we are having some code repetition here, writing `CommonQueryParams` twice:
>
> ```
> commons: CommonQueryParams = Depends(CommonQueryParams)
> ```
>
> FastAPI **provides a shortcut** for these cases, in where the
> dependency is *specifically* a class that FastAPI will "call" to
> create an instance of the class itself.
>
> For those specific cases, you can do the following:
>
> Instead of writing:
>
> ```
> commons: CommonQueryParams = Depends(CommonQueryParams)
> ```
>
> ...you write:
>
> ```
> commons: CommonQueryParams = Depends()
> ```
>
> You declare the dependency as the type of the parameter, and you use
> `Depends()` as its "default" value (that after the `=`) for that
> function's parameter, without any parameter in `Depends()`, instead of
> having to write the full class again inside of
> `Depends(CommonQueryParams)`.