# How to inject Dependenccy in FastAPI

Tags: fastapi

I’m learning how to use the FastAPI in python and I encountered a problem:
How can I initialize a class instance in the main function (for a most configurable code) and inject this object as a dependency to multiple FastAPI endpoint functions

Any help would be much appreciated

I tried to look about router properties and using depends but nothing seems to work

Comment: Please take a look at the link provided above, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71140957/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77651246/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76455768/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75194173/17865804). You might also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322910/17865804) helpful

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74105859/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) as well